# Why am I getting a version compatibility warning with default texlive and biber versions?

Tags: 17.04, latex, texlive

If I produce the very basic LaTeX and BibTeX files

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[german, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,isbn=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ubuntu_biber.bib}

\title{Title1}
\author{Author1}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{Section 1}
Reference: \cite{bibtexkey1}

\end{document}
```

and

```
@InCollection{bibtexkey1,
  Title                    = {Title1},
  Author                   = {Author1},
  Booktitle                = {Booktitle1},
  Publisher                = {Publisher1},
  Year                     = {2000},

  Address                  = {Address1},
  Editor                   = {Editor1},
  Pages                    = {1-2},

  Owner                    = {richter},
  Timestamp                = {2013.09.23}
}
```

I'm getting

```
ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.0, expected version 3.3.
This means that your biber (2.7) and biblatex () versions are incompatible.
```

I don't believe that Ubuntu 17.04 would ship with such a severe error breaking a large part of LaTeX functionality, so what am I doing wrong? I verified this behaviour in a fresh VirtualBox VM with Ubuntu 17.04.

The mentioned compatibilily matrix doesn't seem to exist given that https://github.com/plk/biber is the only updated `biber` page.

MCVE is at https://github.com/krichter722/default-ubuntu-biber-compatibility-mismatch.

The complete output is

```
> pdflatex ubuntu_biber.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./ubuntu_biber.tex
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/german.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/germanb.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/ngerman.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/ngermanb.ldf)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.cfg))
(/home/richter/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/home/richter/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex_.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/home/richter/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(/home/richter/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/home/richter/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex_.def)
(/home/richter/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/authoryear.bbx
(/home/richter/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx))
(/home/richter/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/authoryear.cbx)
(/home/richter/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)))
(/home/richter/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/ngerman.lbx
(/home/richter/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/german.lbx))
No file ubuntu_biber.aux.
No file ubuntu_biber.bbl.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'bibtexkey1' on page 1 undefined on input line 16.

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./ubuntu_biber.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                ubuntu_biber
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 )</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></us
r/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/shar
e/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texli
ve/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texm
f-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb>
Output written on ubuntu_biber.pdf (1 page, 48109 bytes).
Transcript written on ubuntu_biber.log.
richter@richter-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~/Dateien/issues/biber/default-ubuntu-biber-compatibility-mismatch:6734> echo $?
0
> biber ubuntu_biber
INFO - This is Biber 2.7 (beta)
INFO - Logfile is 'ubuntu_biber.blg'
INFO - Reading 'ubuntu_biber.bcf'
Use of uninitialized value $bltxversion in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Biber.pm line 425.
ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.0, expected version 3.3.
This means that your biber (2.7) and biblatex () versions are incompatible.
```